# Similiar Object for Different Use

Tags: oop, kotlin, design-patterns

I have 2 model classes called Assessment.

Assessment for `MainActivity` :

```
data class Assessment(
    val title: String,
    var workouts: List<Workout>
)
```

Assessment for `JourneyActivity` :

```
data class Assessment(
    val title: String,
    val imageUrl: String,
    var workouts: List<Workout>
)
```

those class is instantiate from `retrofit` response

I am wondering should i make it 2 different class or i use `JourneyActivity.Assessment` in `MainActivity` and ignoring variable `imageUrl`? which 1 is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

If you could extend data classes i'd suggest doing so if you really care about dissociating the 2, but you can't, soooo... i guess your best bet is just having one, otherwise it's just duplicate code.